Modelo Entidad Relacion con tabla dinamica sale un 1 y 2?
Tengo dos tablas
la primera tabla es esta empleados:

la segunda tabla es esta tipo de contratos

se fijaron como Primary Key la CC en empleados y en la otra tabla PK Contrato
entonces la relacion es de (empleados) m:1 (tipo de contratos), se hace la realcion por power pivot y que da asi

... incerto la tabla dinamica de la siguiente manera

Pero cuando sale de la siguiente manera

pero en la tabla deberia quedar asi

